# Renaming a replication controller due to ectd error during rolling update

Tags: kubernetes

Is there any way to rename a replication controller for it to be picked up by the rolling update command  ?

The problem is my rolling update failed in the middle with the below error :

> Renaming xx to xx-353rfdf44
>
> Error from server: client: etcd cluster is unavailable or
>   misconfigured; error #0: read tcp
>   172.17.22.102:55398->172.17.22.102:4001: read: connection reset by peer

First of all I dont know why this happend. And second, as you can see, it failed in the rename step. So my rolling update java code, when executed is looking for xx Replication Controller to perform rolling update and since now it is called xx-353rfdf44 , it is not able to find it.

I was wondering if I can do a manual fix to rename xx-353rfdf44 back to xx for my rolling update java code to work again.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

According to [Perform Rolling Update Using a Replication Controller](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/rolling-update-replication-controller/) document:

When rolling update is started, it creates a new replication controller(RC) with updated configuration, then it decreases the number of replicas for the old RC and increases the number of replicas for the new RC until the old RC reaches 0 replicas, and the new RC reaches desired number of replicas. Finally, rolling update deletes the old RC.

There is no way to rename objects in Kubernetes because the name of the object is used as an identifier. [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39428753/9521610)

In your case, it would be better to operate on the level of Deployment object because when rolling update is started for the deployment, it doesn't recreate the deployment object and therefore its name does not change.

Comment: "Finally, rolling update deletes the old RC." that's not correct. Old RSs are kept, because you may want to revert back with "kubectl rollout undo".

Comment: This is what documentation mentioned exactly:  "3. Deleting the original replication controller."

Comment: Create a deployment from a yaml file. Then reedit your file, change image version and reapply the file. You'll see a new RS created, now your deployment resource is managing 2 rs. The old one has zero pods.

Comment: .spec.revisionHistoryLimit is set to 10 by default . This is your history to rollback. Try to set it to 0 and you will have 0 old replicas after update.

Comment: We are planning to move to deployments soon but for now we are using replication controllers. So can I rollback to my previous Replication controller when rolling update fails in the middle after the RC is renamed to xx-353rfdf44 (old one was called xx)  using "kubectl rollout undo" ?

Comment: Rollout strategy can be performed only on daemonset, deployment, statefulset resources.